# Etz Chaim and Torah

Tags: torah-study

What’s the link between Etz Hachaim from Gan Eden and the fact that the Torah itself calls, well, itself, “etz chaim”? Does it maybe have something to do with this thought: although you, Adam, didn’t eat from the tree of life and gain eternal life, I am granting you the gift of Torah to be as an “etz chaim” to you and as a way to “obtain a longer life”

Comment: https://outorah.org/p/37727/ towards the end of the article

Comment: Rav Naḥman bar Yitzḥak said: Why are Torah matters likened to a tree, as it is stated: “It is a tree of life to them who lay hold upon it” (Proverbs 3:18)? This verse comes to tell you that just as a small piece of wood can ignite a large piece, so too, minor Torah scholars can sharpen great Torah scholars and enable them to advance in their studies. - Taanis 7a

Comment: See also Rashi on Avos 6:7: He eats its fruits in this world, and the principle is preserved for him in the world to come. - we study Torah and observe mitzvos (we taste the fruit) and we get rewarded in the life to come.

Comment: I also highly recommend reading Kuntres Eitz HaChayim, available fully translated and explained here: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/144473/jewish/The-Tree-of-Life-Kuntres-Eitz-HaChayim.htm